# z-index of child override by parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have requirement like my page content goes between header and logo(ie above header image and below logo image).

```html
//header
<div class="header">Header image
    //logo
    <div class="logo">Logo Image</div>
</div>

//content
<div class="content">
    my page content
</div>
```

```css
header {
    left: 63.3167px;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 19px;
    width: 1456px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

logo {
    z-index: 1006;
}

content {
    z-index: 1004;
}
```

When I scroll the page, content goes either below (header z-index > content) or above(header z-index < content)  the header image.Not meet my requirement.
I have set z-index value of header,logo and content as 1000,1004 and 1002 resp. I think header div(parent) z-index overrides logo(child) z-index value. So it goes either below or above header

Any suggestion please.

Comment: whats the question? you say " it goes either below or above header" are you suggesting its random? is there more css to this problem?

Comment: please give demo in jsfiidle

Answer (score 3):

First of all you're missing a selector `.` and to allow z-indexing you must explictly define the position:

```
  .header {
  left: 63.3167px;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 19px;
  width: 1456px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.logo{
  z-index: 1006;
  position: relative;/*or absolute*/
}

.content{
 z-index: 1004;
position: relative;/*or absolute*/
}
```

Comment: Even though you solved the basic mistakes, the z-index problem is un-solved. see http://jsfiddle.net/ckL4o3v9/

Answer (score 1):

Hope you got the understand from this code snaps

```css
.header {
    position:fixed;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color:red;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
}

.logo {
    position:fixed;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    z-index: +5;
    background-color:green;
    left:60px;
    top:60px;
}

.content {
    position:fixed;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    z-index: +2;
    background-color:blue;
    left:40px;
    top:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header image

</div>
    <div class="logo">Logo Image</div>

<div class="content">
    my page content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @NifrasIsmail for your time. But my logo image is inside header(header div is parent and logo div its child). Header and logo have different z-index value. Content should scroll in between header and logo(above header and below logo).